# Is it possible to place search.php, searchform.php and content-search.php all into the same folder and still be able to successfully call them?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to be able to place the below files into a folder, entitled 'search' and still be able to successfully call them:

- search.php
- searchform.php
- content-search.php

For context, I have placed `<div class="search-form-container"><?php get_search_form(); ?></div>` into my **header.php** file.  Currently, my **searchform.php** and **search.php** files are in the following directory:

/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/[theme-name]/
.

My **content-search.php** file is in my 'search' folder where I am calling this in my **search.php** file by using the following code:

```
<?php get_template_part('search/content', 'search');
```

In simple terms, I have successfully achieved my goal for my **content-search.php** file and wondering if anyone knows how I can achieve the same for the other 2 files?

Comment: I don't know if my comment is too much ignorant but I need to ask: do you have tried to do the same for this 2 other files?

Comment: RokumDev:  As in 'have I entered `<?php get_template_part('search', 'search');` and `<?php get_template_part('search', 'searchform');`' instead of  `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` If this is a possible direction, how would I go about it?  Firstly, I would be replacing one entry with two and the code syntax is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put 'search.php' into the root of the theme.  For other template files, you can place them inside another folder but it will not necessarily be a good idea.  This is because the 'searchform.php' file is used by the Search Widget and thus needs to be placed within the root of the theme.  That said, you can place your file in any other folder (with no problems), if you are just going to manually call it.  Just make sure you call the correct file path.